# Find the contour with largest enclosing area using OpenCV (Python)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, contour, canny-operator

I have an image [Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGVTj.jpg), and I would like to find the contour that encloses the box in the image. The reason for doing this, is I would like to then crop the image to the bounding box, and then perform further image processing on this cropped image.

I have tried detecting Canny edges, however they seem not to be connecting as I want them to. Attached is an image of how the canny edges look. [Canny edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQHyy.png)

```
    gray = img[:,:,1]
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 20, 60)
```

What is the best way to find the bounding box from the original image?

Many thanks.

Let me know how I can make this question clearer if possible too!

Answer (score 0):

I assume the following: (if this is not the case you should specify such things in your question)
You know the size of the box
The size is always the same
The perspective is always the same
The box is always completely within the field of fiew
The box is not rotated

Use a few scan lines across the image to find the transition from black background to box (in x and y)
Threshold exceeded, max gradient or whatever suits you best.

Discard outliers, use min and max coordinates to position the fixed size ROI over your box.

There are many other ways to find the center positon of that fixed ROI like

threshold, distance transform, maximum

or

threshold, blob search, centroid/contour

You could also do some contour matching.

I recommend you improve your setup so the background illumination does not exceed the box border (left/right is better than top/bottom). Then everything becomes easy.

Your edge image looks terrible btw. Check other methods or improve your Canny parameters.